# Comparing Input Values with Single Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to verify an ID from a button being clicked, does not already exist in a set of inputs.

Code that gets ID from button clicked

```
   $(".detail-view button").on("click", function() {
       var detailID = $(this).attr('id');
```

Code that checks ID doesn't exist

```
function itemExists() {
    $("input#lunchorder_item_entry_id").each(function() {
        existingID = $(this).val();

        if(detailID == existingID) {
           alert("You have already added this item. If you want to change item details, please remove the item and re-add it to your cart. Thank You!");
        } else {

       }
    });
}
```

The issue I'm having this only works part of the time, if anyone has a suggestion on a better way to do this I'm sure this isn't the best way to achieve my goal. Thank you!

Comment: There is a scope issue, `detailID` is not a global variable in your code. In the context of `itemExists` function, it is

Comment: change `$(this).attr('id');` to `this.id`
this way you save the `this` to be converted in a jQuery Object and access the `id` attribute directly instead of access it by one more function..

Comment: Ok, I should mention that the function `itemExists` is within my on click function.

Answer (score 0):

`detailID` isn't visible in your `itemExists()` function, either make it global, or pass it to the function.

```
itemExists(detailID){
  // if(detailID == existingID) {
}
```

The whole this should look something like this

```
 $(".detail-view button").on("click", function() {
       var detailID = $(this).attr('id');
       itemExists(detailID);
 });
 function itemExists(detailID) {
    $("input#lunchorder_item_entry_id").each(function() {
            var existingID = $(this).val();
            if(detailID == existingID) {
               alert("You have already added this item. If you want to change item details, please remove the item and re-add it to your cart. Thank You!");
            } else {

            }
     });
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't really fix my issue, because it still allows things to fire the else. I think really what I need is a way to put each value and compare against the array.